# PostgreSQL SELECT can alter a table?

Tags: postgresql

So I'm new to SQL like databases and the place that I work at migrated to PostgreSQL. One table drastically reduced its contents. The point is, I only used SELECT statements, and changed the name of the columns with AS. Is there a way I might have changed the table data?

Comment: in sql you use delete or truncate to remove rows from a table
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-delete.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-truncate.html

Comment: It can if the `SELECT` was calling a function or procedure that deleted rows. Otherwise someone/something else is calling `DELETE/TRUNCATE` queries. Time to look at the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the only thing I did was use "AS" to rename the columns of the querry return. Is "AS" statement able to change the table?

Comment: No. At some point a `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` has to be used. Look at the Postgres logs, that will tell you what was run against the database. Another possibility is you have the same table name in multiple schema and you are looking at the wrong one when you look at the contents. While we are on the subject how are determining that the table had rows deleted? Add as update to your question.

Comment: There is reason SELECT is called SELECT and not DELETE or TRUNCATE. What you mention here, is impossible. No database, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL or whatever, will delete something when you want to select something. Never. There must be a DELETE statements somewhere to delete data. And that can be in a function that you have called, using a SELECT statement. That is possible, but it's still the DELETE command that does the DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

When you migrate from a DBMS to another DBMS you must be sure that the objects created are strictly equivalent... The question seems to be trivial, but is'nt.

As a matter fact one important consideration for litterals (char/varchar...) is to verify the collation used formerly and the collation you have used to create the newly database in PostGreSQL.

Collation in an RDBMS is the way to adjust the behavior of character strings with regard to certain parameters such as the distinction, or not, of upper and lower case letters, the distinction, or not, of diacritical characters (accents, ligatures...), specific sorting to language, etc. And constitutes a superset of the character encoding.

Did you verify this point when using some WHERE clause to search some litterals ? If not, try to restricts litteral in applying the right collation (COLLATE operator) or use UPPER function to avoid the distinguish between upper and lower chars...